# CancellationToken with await Task

Tags: wpf, task

I want to use CancellationToken in my GUI but it doesn't work.
When I click on the cancel button I want to cancel the operation

```
 this.tokenSource.Cancel();
```

In other place I have other button that  need to do main operation. The main part  includes Task and CancellationToken token and this part doesn works

```
private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;

private async void DataSynchronization(object notInUse)
    {
        this.tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken ct = new CancellationToken();
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {

            try
            {

            // do main operation 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
               // final operation 
            }
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {

                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }


        }, this.tokenSource.Token)
            .ContinueWith(
                completedTaskResult =>
                {
                    // I want to check if cancel was presed
                }
            );


    }
```

This is main structure but something wrong. I don't receive cancel operation

Comment: Can you provide example please?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here. First you shouldn't create your own `CancellationToken`, that's what `CancellationTokenSource` is for! It's the *source* for your *token*. Second, you should use the `Run` overload that takes a `CancellationToken` as the second argument, and third, you need to check the `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` property in your `do main operation` to see if it's been cancelled and *stop doing what you are doing* if it is.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160373(v=vs.110).aspx) for a good example.

So you code might end up looking something like:

```
this.tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = tokenSource.Token;

await Task.Run(() =>
{
    while(notDone && !token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
}, token);
```

Now when you do:

`this.tokenSource.Cancel();`

It will signal to the associated `Token` that the operation is cancelled and somewhere inside your task you'll pick that up and stop doing that thing.

Comment: Am I understand correctly notDone  should be updated inside the task on the end of the operation?The last step to use ContinueWith with TaskStatus.Canceled?

Comment: @Leo, it's just illustrating a loop. The important part is to be checking the `token` and some convenient point during your task. You can also register a callback on the token if that's more easier.